# Image links broken / "DNS Update Required" message

Tags: images, dns

absolute mess of a WP migration.

The basic breakdown of this problem is that I have a collection of images from old blog posts that are not loading, but the posts themselves are. I have, at best, a rudimentary understanding of how this works, so this may be a fairly straightforward fix.

For instance:

https://www.themagazineantiques.com/article/breaking-tradition-ceramics-by-michelle-erickson/

You'll notice no images appear, though when they were crawled in january, they were present:

https://web.archive.org/web/20190110140219/http://www.themagazineantiques.com/article/breaking-tradition-ceramics-by-michelle-erickson/

The current display has all the text from the old post, and points to the images:

```
 <p><img id="image_5525" src="http://antiquesmag.wpengine.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/01/21/img-news-erickson-6_171133725846.jpg" alt="" width="472" height="365" />
```

But the image src links redirect to a page that says: "DNS Update Required

The site you were looking for is no longer available at this IP address.
This IP address is deprecated and is no longer able to serve the requested domain.

If this is your site, please update your DNS to use the correct IP address or CNAME."

**My coworker and I intend to update the DNS A Record and CNAME via GoDaddy's hosting portal; but my question is: will this reconnect the images?**

I worry it won't because when I check in the WP Media Library, the image "appears" as an entry, but does not actually appear - attached image below to clarify that a bit.

[image]

Comment: Have you checked via FTP to see whether the images are actually on the new server? Two things could be happening - either the images did copy over onto your new host, but they're not referenced correctly in the database; or else the images didn't copy over from the old host and you need to retrieve them from a backup.

Comment: To be honest, no - and I wouldn't know how to. We've reached out to GoDaddy support, and I'll mention this to them to see - I think they handled the migration. Thank you!

Comment: @WebElaine if it is the second scenario; is there a method of batch reuploading the images and connecting them?

Comment: As long as nothing has changed since you imported the database, if you uploaded the images to the same folders on the new site they were in on the old site - uploading meaning using FTP to put them on the server, not using the Media Library - they should work. However, if you have to resort to loading them through the Media Library, you'll have to go through your entire site's content replacing images because they will have different URLs and IDs.